# is it possible to write an es6 onChange arrow function?

Tags: ecmascript-6

What's the correct syntax for the onChange es6 function?

```js
function myEvent(e){
console.log(e.target)
}
```

```html
<select onChange=(event)=>{console.log(event.target)}>
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>


<select onChange={console.log(event.target)}>
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>


<select onChange="myEvent(event)">
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

<select onChange=function(){console.log("hello"))>
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i mean, certainly you wouldn't put it in the html,

Comment: In what context, exactly?

Comment: why can't you place an es6 arrow function or an anonymous function in the html?

Comment: generally we avoid putting javascript in html attributes now days, outside of things like react/angular and similar

Comment: I understand, but is it possible?

Comment: depends on what you deem acceptable, and consider "es6"

Comment: as in the example in the snippet?  Is it possible?

Comment: only one of your options use an arrow function, and it wouldn't actually do anything because creating a function within an event callback doesn't make sense. (and it's invalid as written)

Comment: The code you put into the html attribute is itself turned into a function, defining an arrow function there doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: What problem are you REALLY trying to solve here and why are you explicitly asking for an arrow function?

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible to have a multi line function embedded in the html.  Appears the answer is no

Comment: Then, why don't you edit your question to actually ask "if it was possible to have a multi line function embedded in the html".  That is not at all what your current question communicates at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was just wondering if it was possible to have a multi line function embedded in the html. Appears the answer is n

You can. The value of the `on*` attributes become *the body* of a function. Therefore you can define a function inline but you also have to call it.

For example:

```html
<select onChange="function foo(){
  console.log('hello')
}
foo();">
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

<!-- as IIFE -->
<select onChange="(function(){console.log('hello')}())">
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

<!-- of course that works with arrow functions too -->
<select onChange="(() => {console.log('hello')
                           console.log('goodbye')})()">
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: wow, that's terrific!.  I was getting so many wrong answers from others who responded.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the event as a parameter to the js function and use it there

```js
const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  const selectedValue = e.target.value;
  console.log(selectedValue)
}
```

```html
<select onChange="onChangeHandler(event)">
  <option value="5"> 5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks you!  I was just wondering if your could place the es6 function directly into the html.  But it appears that you can't.  Nice work around

Answer (score -1):

**Inline javascript context you can do**
**ARROW Function**

```
<select onchange="(() => console.log(event.target.value))()">
```

**REACTJS Context**
check curly braces and event.target.value

```
<select onChange={(event) => console.log(event.target.value) }>
        <option value="5"> 5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

<select onChange={(event) => {console.log(event.target.value)} }>
        <option value="5"> 5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: and neither work

Comment: @DCR Hope this w'll help

Answer (score -2):

This is not an actual answer but a demonstration that the task at hand can be done in a much easier way.

```js
document.body.onchange=e=>{
  console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option> 5</option>
  <option> 6</option>
  <option>15</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option> 5</option>
  <option> 7</option>
  <option>15</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option> 5</option>
  <option> 8</option>
  <option>15</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option> 5</option>
  <option> 9</option>
  <option>15</option>
</select>
```